# Como checar se uma resposta (data) é um json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Como posso verificar se um resultado (data) vindo de uma requisição ajax é um json ou nao? Tentei esse codigo mas nao obtive exito

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(response);

            if(obj.avatar) {
            } else {
            }
```

Comment: A pergunta está confusa. JSon é uma string formatada e o `parseJSON` do JQuery cria uma estrutura de objetos a partir desta string. Informe a string que você tem em `response`. Obs: se a string for inválida, `$.parseJSON` lança uma exceção.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu bem seu problema. Não se esqueça de aceitar uma delas. Seria legal se você puder revisar suas perguntas. Eu noto que existem muitas respostas muito boas para elas que poderiam ser aceitas e que você não o fez.

Answer (score 9):

O [método `parseJSON` do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) lança uma exceção se o JSON não for válido. Portanto:

```
var obj;
try {
    obj = $.parseJSON(response);
    // use o JSON aqui
} catch(ex) {
    // trate o erro aqui
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução com JavaScript nativo [sugerido no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20392392/2256325) seria:

```
function testarJSON (jsonString){
    try {
        var o = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        if (o && typeof o === "object" && o !== null) return o;
    }
    catch (e) { }
    return false;
};
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
var jsonValido = '{ "time": "03:53:25 AM", "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1362196405309, "date": "03-02-2013" }';
var jsonInvalido = '"time": "03:53:25 AM", "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1362196405309, "date": "03-02-2013"';

function testarJSON (jsonString){
    try {
        var o = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        if (o && typeof o === "object" && o !== null) return o;
    }
    catch (e) { }
    return false;
};

alert('Nr de JSONs válidos: ' + [jsonValido, jsonInvalido].filter(testarJSON).length);
```

Comment: #Revivendo, tive problemas com a funçao ela me retorna false nessa string, por que? Como adaptar pra evitar? `Object {response: "sucess_generation"} (index):11 false` (é uma copia do console)

Comment: @user3163662 dá uma olhada na consola e vê o que o servidor envia. Coloca também um `console.log(typeof jsonString, jsonString);` antes to `try{` e diz o que dá.

Comment: 1 - o cod que me mandastes 2 - a string a ser verificada 3 o error http://imgur.com/XdIZIIl

Comment: @user3163662 ok, o objeto já está traduzido. Então faz somente `if (typeof jsonString == 'object') return jsonString;` antes do `try{`.

Comment: @user3163662 Crie um [exemplo que reproduza o problema](/help/mcve).